# Trying to use PHPMailer to send mass-emails

Tags: php, loops, email, while-loop, phpmailer

everyone!

I've to send monthly a lot of a emails with a QRcode png in attachment. Because of that, i'm planning change my script with the 'built-in' mail() function to use PHPMailer class.

The problem is, by using the PHPMailer class, only the first database query receive the email.

If could be useful, i'm attaching my script below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Envio de chaves PIX por email em massa</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?=SITE_IMAGES_PATH?>favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<a name='topo'></a>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// page setup
ob_start();
session_start();
require('../constants.php');
require('../functions.php');
require('../db.php');
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require('../mailer/src/Exception.php');
require('../mailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
require('../mailer/src/SMTP.php');

// codificação
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
@ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');

// dados de permissoes
try{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . CONFIG;
    $configdata = $link->prepare($sql);
    $configdata->execute();
    $data = $configdata->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(PDOException $error){
    die($error->getMessage());
}
if(!empty($_COOKIE['user']) && empty($_SESSION['id'])){
    $logindata = unserialize($_COOKIE['user']);
    try{
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM " . USERS . " WHERE user = :user AND pass = :pass";
        $sessionmngt = $link->prepare($sql1);
        $sessionmngt->bindValue(':user',$logindata['user']);
        $sessionmngt->bindValue(':pass',$logindata['pass']);
        $sessionmngt->execute();
        $userdata = $sessionmngt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch(PDOException $error){
        die($error->getMessage());
    }
    $_SESSION['id']     = $userdata['id'];
    $_SESSION['user']   = $userdata['user'];
    $_SESSION['pass']   = $userdata['pass'];
    $_SESSION['level']  = $userdata['level'];
    $_SESSION['status'] = $userdata['status'];
}
$config = array(0=>'Visitante',1=>'Usuário',2=>'Moderador',3=>'Administrador',4=>'FUCKING GOD',5=>'Ninguém');
$status = array(0=>'Desativado',1=>'Ativo');
(!isset($_SESSION['level'])) ? $_SESSION['level'] = 0 : NULL;

if(isset($_SESSION['level']) ? $_SESSION['level']>=ROOT : NULL)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . EMPRESAS;
    $empresas = $link->prepare($sql);
    $empresas->execute();

    if(isset($_GET['lista']) ? $_GET['lista'] == 'enviar' : NULL)
    {
        while($empresa = $empresas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            var_dump($empresa);
            try
            {           
                /********************************************************
                *
                *   RELACIONAMENTO EMPRESA X MODALIDADE
                *
                ********************************************************/
                $sql = "SELECT id,valor,nome_modalidade FROM " . MODALIDADES . " 
                        INNER JOIN " . EMP_MODALIDADES . " ON " . MODALIDADES . ".mid = " . EMP_MODALIDADES . ".mid
                        WHERE eid=:eid";
                $consulta_modalidades = $link->prepare($sql);
                $consulta_modalidades->bindValue(':eid',$empresa['id']);
                $consulta_modalidades->execute();
            }
            catch(PDOException $error)
            {
                die($error->getMessage());
            }

            $chave_pix          ="04729502000109";
            $beneficiario_pix   ="FUNDEPI";
            $cidade_pix         ="PRES PRUDENTE";
            $identificador      ="***";
            $descricao          ="";
            $gerar_qrcode=true;
            
            while($modalidade = $consulta_modalidades->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                /**************************************************

                *   INICIO - GERAR QRCode

                ***************************************************/
                $chave_pix="04729502000109";
                $beneficiario_pix="FUNDEPI";
                $cidade_pix="PRES PRUDENTE";
                $identificador="***";
                $descricao="";
                $gerar_qrcode=true;
                $valor_pix=preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/","",$modalidade['valor']);

                if ($gerar_qrcode)
                {
                    include "phpqrcode/qrlib.php"; 
                    include "funcoes_pix.php";
                    $px[00]="01"; //Payload Format Indicator, Obrigatório, valor fixo: 01
                    // Se o QR Code for para pagamento único (só puder ser utilizado uma vez), descomente a linha a seguir.
                    //$px[01]="12"; //Se o valor 12 estiver presente, significa que o BR Code só pode ser utilizado uma vez. 
                    $px[26][00]="BR.GOV.BCB.PIX"; //Indica arranjo específico; “00” (GUI) obrigatório e valor fixo: br.gov.bcb.pix
                    $px[26][01]=$chave_pix;
                    if (!empty($descricao))
                    {
                        $tam_max_descr=99-(4+4+4+14+strlen($chave_pix));
                        if (strlen($descricao) > $tam_max_descr)
                        {
                            $descricao=substr($descricao,0,$tam_max_descr);
                        }
                        $px[26][02]=$descricao;
                    }
                    $px[52]="0000"; //Merchant Category Code “0000” ou MCC ISO18245
                    $px[53]="986"; //Moeda, “986” = BRL: real brasileiro - ISO4217
                    $px[54]=$valor_pix;
                    $px[58]="BR"; //“BR” – Código de país ISO3166-1 alpha 2
                    $px[59]=$beneficiario_pix; //Nome do beneficiário/recebedor. Máximo: 25 caracteres.
                    $px[60]=$cidade_pix; //Nome cidade onde é efetuada a transação. Máximo 15 caracteres.
                    $px[62][05]=$identificador;
                    $px[62][50][00]="BR.GOV.BCB.BRCODE"; //Payment system specific template - GUI
                    $px[62][50][01]="1.0.0"; //Payment system specific template - versão
                    $pix=montaPix($px);
                    $pix.="6304"; //Adiciona o campo do CRC no fim da linha do pix.
                    $pix.=crcChecksum($pix); //Calcula o checksum CRC16 e acrescenta ao final.
                    $linhas=round(strlen($pix)/40)+1;
                    ?>
                    Modalidade: <?=$modalidade['nome_modalidade']?>
                    <br />
                    Valor: R$ <?=$valor_pix?>,00
                    <p>
                    <img src="logo_pix.png"><br>
                    <?php
                    ob_start();
                    QRCode::png($pix, null,'M',5);
                    $imageString = base64_encode(ob_get_contents());
                    ob_end_clean();
                }
                /**************************************************

                *   FIM - GERAR QRCode

                ***************************************************/
                /***********************************************
                
                    DADOS DO Email
                    
                    ***********************************************/
                $valor_pix      = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/","",$modalidade['valor']);
                $uid            = md5(uniqid(time()));
                $remetente      = "financeiro@inovaprudente.com.br";
                $nome_remetente = "Departamento Financeiro - Fundação Inova Prudente";
                $headers        = "From: " . $nome_remetente . " <" . $remetente . ">\r\n";
                $headers        .= "Reply-To: " . $remetente . "\r\n";
                $headers        .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers        .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $uid . "\"\r\n\r\n";
                $destinatario   = "financeiro@inovaprudente.com.br"; //$empresa['email'];
                $assunto        = "Chave PIX para " . $empresa['nome'];
                $corpo          = "<!DOCTYPE html>
                                    <html>
                                    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />
                                    <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">
                                    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\" />" .
                                    "Saudações, " . $empresa['nome'] . "!
                                    <br /><br />
                                    Segue os dados do PIX para quitação da mensalidade.
                                    <br /><br />
                                    O QRCode correspondente está anexo a este email, mas você também poderá usar a linha digitável para pagamento, caso não tenha um celular por perto ;)
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <b>Modalidade:</b> " . $modalidade['nome_modalidade'] . "
                                    <br />
                                    <b>Valor:</b> R$ " . $modalidade['valor'] . ",00
                                    <br />
                                    <b>Linha digitável:</b> <font face='Courier New'>" . $pix . "</font>
                                    <br /><br />
                                    Estamos realizando testes com o sistema de cobrança PIX para que em breve possamos migrar nosso sistema de cobrança. Estamos enviando essa mensagem contendo um QRcode (e sua chave correspondente) para que possamos confirmar o seu recebimento. NÃO EFETUE O PAGAMENTO! Agradeceríamos se, em vez disso, nos desse um feedback informando se: 1) o email caiu na sua caixa de SPAM e 2) se o app do seu banco pôde fazer a leitura do código QRcode.
                                    <br /><br />
                                    Grato pela vossa atenção.
                                    <br /><br />
                                    At.te,  
                                    <br />
                                    Fernando
                                    </html>";
                $email = new PHPMailer();
                $email->Encoding = 'base64';
                $email->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
                /*
                $mail->IsSMTP();                            // set mailer to use SMTP
                $mail->Host = 'mail.blah.com';    // specify main mail server
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                        // turn on SMTP authentication
                $mail->Username = 'myusername';                // SMTP username
                $mail->Password = 'my***password';            // SMTP password
                
                $mail->From = 'alerts@remindalert.com';
                $mail->FromName = 'RA Mailer';
                */
                $email->SetFrom($remetente, $nome_remetente);
                $email->Subject = $assunto;
                $email->isHTML(true);
                $email->Body    = $corpo;
                //mail->AltBody = "Mensagem simplificada.";
                $email->AddAddress($destinatario);
                $file_to_attach = '../mailer/tmp/';
                // Exibe a imagem diretamente ao cliente codificada em base64.
                //echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $imageString . '"></p>';
                $filename = 'Chave PIX.png';
                $email->addStringAttachment(base64_decode($imageString), $filename);

                return $email->Send();
                
                if(!$mail->Send())
                {
                    echo "Erro no envio do email: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Deu bom!";
                }
                $email->ClearAllRecipients(); //necessario para a proxima iteracao
            }
        }
    }
    /***********************************************

    *   APENAS LISTA OS DESTINATARIOS

    *************************************************/
    ?>
    <div class='divtab' id='whitebody'>
        <table id='yellowborder' align="center">
            <tr>
                <td class='title'>Nome</td>
                <td class='title'>Chaves PIX</td>
                <td class='title'>Email</td>
                <td class='title'>Celular</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            while($empresa = $empresas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . EMP_MODALIDADES . " WHERE eid=:eid";
                $modalidades = $link->prepare($sql);
                $modalidades->bindParam(':eid',$empresa['id']);
                $modalidades-> execute();
                ?>
                <tr class='trhover'>
                    <td class='cell'><b><a href="<?="../empresas.php?modo=visualizar&id=" . $empresa['id']?>" title='Clique para ver detalhes'><?=$empresa['nome']?></a></b></td>
                    <td align='center'>
                        <?php
                            while($modalidade = $modalidades->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                            {
                                ?><a target='_blank' onclick="window.open('./qrcode_empresas.php?id=<?=$empresa['id']?>&mid=<?=$modalidade['mid']?>', '_blank','menubar=no,resizable=no, scrollbars=no, status=no, titlebar=no, toolbar=no, width=600, height=600')"><img class='imgbutton' src='.<?=SITE_IMAGES_PATH?>qrcode.png' alt='Será gerada uma chave temporária no valor da mensalidade' title='Será gerada uma chave temporária no valor da mensalidade' style='margin-left: 7px; width:25px; '></a><?php
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class='cell'><?=$empresa['email']?></td>
                    <td class='cell'><?=$empresa['celular']?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php
}
else
{
    die(FORBIDDEN_ERROR);
}
?>
<br />
</html>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) - you could probably improve the efficiency of what you're doing so far. I'd also recommend making your script less monolithic - break it up into small pieces that link together and you should find it easier to work with.

I think your immediate problem is simply this:

```
return $email->Send();
```

That will send the first email, then quit! Just delete the `return` (and maybe add some error handling as per the example) and the loop will be able to continue.

Comment: Man, you're right! Thank you. 

Now i've got a lot of errors envolving the qrcode impementation, just going to work on then.